# How to replace "CREATE VIEW", "CREATE PROCEDURE", "CREATE FUNCTION", "CREATE TRIGGER" in SQL files?

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a method which processes a large number of SQL procedures written by our previous SQL developer.

I am trying to search the files for the following strings `CREATE VIEW`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, `CREATE TRIGGER`.

- The search for these strings in the file needs to be case-insensitive
  and should match for any number of spaces between each element, e.g.
  `CREATE VIEW` or `CREATE      VIEW`.
- When it finds a match it needs to replace the `CREATE` with `CREATE OR ALTER`.
- The script shall ignore occurrences such as `CREATE TABLE`.
- The script shall ignore occurrences such as `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`.

I started by writing a procedure to process the files line by line (this is because the text to search is always contained within the line), but I got stuck...

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This method process each individual line executing the replacement where necessary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="line"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string ProcessLine(string line)
{
// how do I perform the logic here?
    return line;
}

/// <summary>
/// This method will process each individual file and create a new file with the _new suffix
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file"></param>
public static void ProcessSqlFile(FileInfo file)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
    {
        sb.Append(ProcessLine(lines[i]));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    var outputName = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, file.Name +"_new");
    File.WriteAllText(outputName, sb.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"...");
    var files = inputPath.GetFiles("*.sql");

    foreach (var fileInfo in files)
    {
        ProcessSqlFile(fileInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). Replace `\bcreate\s+(view|procedure|function|trigger)\b` with `CREATE OR ALTER $1` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbcreate%5cs%2b%28view%7cprocedure%7cfunction%7ctrigger%29%5cb&i=I+am+trying+to+search+the+files+for+the+following+strings+%22CREATE+VIEW%22%2c+%22CREATE+PROCEDURE%22%2c+%22CREATE+FUNCTION%22%2c+%22CREATE+TRIGGER%22%0d%0a%0d%0a&r=CREATE+OR+ALTER+%241&o=i)).

Comment: Could you provide a working example. I am not sure I understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: Don't forget `CREATE PROC`. Any solution involving Regex etc is going to bug out on `SELECT 'CREATE TABLE' FROM...` Hopefully you don't have that issue.

Comment: You want to replace CREATE sql_object except tables with CREATE OR ALTER . Try to put as the request at the beginning or change the title. Try to explain why you are stuck? Every file has only one CREATE ?

Comment: detzu, not every file has one create. It can have multiple CREATE statements.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) (AKA, Regex) for this. For example, you may use the following pattern:

```
\bcreate\s+(view|procedure|function|trigger)\b
```

..and replace with:

```
CREATE OR ALTER $1
```

**[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbcreate%5Cs%2B%28view%7Cprocedure%7Cfunction%7Ctrigger%29%5Cb&i=I%20am%20trying%20to%20search%20the%20files%20for%20the%20following%20strings%20%22CREATE%20VIEW%22%2C%20%22CREATE%20PROCEDURE%22%2C%20%22CREATE%20FUNCTION%22%2C%20%22CREATE%20TRIGGER%22%0D%0A%0D%0A&r=CREATE%20OR%20ALTER%20%241&o=i)**.

**Regex pattern details:**

- `\b` - Ensure a word boundary (avoid matching partial words).
- `\s+` - Match one or more whitespace characters.
- `(view|procedure|function|trigger)` - Match any of the listed words and capture it in group 1.
- `\b` Ensure a word boundary.

**Replacement:**

- `CREATE OR ALTER`  - Literal string.
- `$1` - Whatever was captured in group 1.

**Full C# example:**

```cs
string input = "I am trying to search the files for the following strings " +
               "CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE TRIGGER";

string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\bcreate\s+(view|procedure|function|trigger)\b",
                              @"CREATE OR ALTER $1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CMQT42773)**.

---

**Disclaimer:**

As [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) and [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) indicated in the comments, this (and similar solutions) would match false positives in string literals. If you might have those, you'd be better off using an SQL parser as a regex pattern would be overly complicated, in this case, if we wish to cover all edge cases.

Comment: Now to make sure it doesn't process string literals.

Comment: @GSerg Yep, a regex pattern will be overly complicated in that case. If the OP has this problem, I would suggest using a parser.

Comment: Thank you this is indeed very clean. I wish I was that good using regex

Answer (score 0):

the solution that seems to me to be the simplest is not making use of regex, but plain text processing.

I tried to run the following method on a few sql files and it looked good to me.

```
    private static string ProcessLine(string line)
    {
        if (!line.ToUpper().Contains("CREATE"))
        {
            return line;
        }
        var wordArray = line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (wordArray[i].ToUpper() != "CREATE" ||
                (wordArray[i + 1].ToUpper() != "VIEW" && wordArray[i + 1].ToUpper() != "PROCEDURE" && wordArray[i + 1].ToUpper() != "FUNCTION" && wordArray[i + 1].ToUpper() != "TRIGGER")) continue;
            return line.Replace("CREATE", "CREATE OR ALTER");
        }
        return line;
    }
```

Comment: @SimonFridman No, it doesn't work. It *could* on some files, but not in principle. It's unable to handle the situation when `create` and `view` are on different lines, when `create` is the last word on the line, and when the line contains other, unrelated instances of the text "create" (e.g. in string literals).

Comment: In the question is clearly stated that the text to search is always contained within the line. I would read the question before downgrading.

Comment: using ToUpper/ToLower instead of String.Equals with a IgnoreCase option is really not a good thing to do.